# Silent Printing from Web Page

Tags: plugins, printing, cross-browser

I am working on a web application that needs silent printing (without print dialog box) with client side printer.

After some research we found that we can make it work using ActiveX and Foxit Reader.

Currently it works great but it constraints us with IE only and we want to make it work with Firefox and Chrome as well.

I know there is no direct code to make it work, but there must a work around?

What I need is the point to start e.g. Chrome/Firefox plugins to access local printer - or make windows service that runs in background in the client side, change browser settings, use ActionScript etc.

It will also be great if someone also illustrate how Facebook access local webcam from its website it may make about accessing clients peripherals from website. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe Facebook is using Flash to access the local webcam. I think researching the options Flash has for printing, might give you a good start. Don't know if it is possible though, but worth a try.

Comment: a custom http handler bound to a small custom application which performs the printing task might accomplish this (something similar to ed2k links handling by emule, i'm not sure about how to "send" data to the app though)

Comment: can you point us to some more information on how you got it to work with activex and foxit reader?

Comment: Google has a sample extension for printing in the following link: [Chrome print extension](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html#e6ae17ab4ccfd7e059c8c01f25760ca5d894c7fd) It may be give some idea about printing.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who still wants information regarding printing on Chrome and/or FireFox without the use of ActiveX, extensions or client-side scripting, please see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36603281/5516239) to another question similar to this.